# python multiprocessing does not run at same time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to make a python program that runs multiple processes each in an infinite loop at the same time, but only one process will execute at a time, the first one in code, then the rest of the program will not run. What do i need to do to make both procceses and the main one execute at the same time?

```
from multiprocessing import *
import time


def test1(q):
    while True:
        q.put("Banana")
        time.sleep(2)



def test2(q):
    while True:
        q.put("internet")
        time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     q = Queue()
     t1 = Process(target=test1(q))
     t2 = Process(target=test2(q))
     t1.start()
     t2.start()
     q.put("rice")
     while True:
         print(q.get())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your problem is with the lines:

```
     t1 = Process(target=test1(q))
     t2 = Process(target=test2(q))
```

There you will actually call `test1` and `test2`, respectively (even though you will never reach the `test2` call). After running the functions it will then use the return result a `target`. What you want is:

```
     t1 = Process(target=test1, args=(q,))
     t2 = Process(target=test2, args=(q,))
```

Thus, you do not want to actually run the `test1` and `test2`functions, but use their references (addresses) as `target` and then you have to provide their input arguments in a separate parameter `args`.